# How to use previous in crystal report and display not null.

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I want to suppress the duplicate and display only one value but the previous is only displaying the first record i have first record blank or "null" and the second is not null the previous is displaying the first value.

Comment: Hi Matt, could you please elaborate the current output and expected output further?  

If you have a data set as follows.  What do you need to display finally.
NAME AGE
Peter 30
Fin 20
Peter 34
Peter 12

Comment: @Anura Adikari 
Current:
NAME         AGE
Peter           30
"Null"            30
"Null"             20
 Fin               20

output i want:
NAME         AGE
Peter           30
 Fin              20

remove all with null value rows. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I Solved my problem using this codes.

PreviousIsNull({@Q3}) or {@Q3} <> Previous({@Q3}) and  PreviousIsNull({@E3}) or {@E3} <> Previous({@E3});

Answer (score 0):

Select the field you want and select on the properties suppress on duplicate